# How to SQL - use of Aggregate function SUM in alias column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to calculate the sum of  column alias  "Performance_Indicators". 
I want to total the sum of Performance_Indicator. 
I cannot use SUM(Performance_Indicators).

```
SELECT    a.username
          ,a.name
          ,a.description
          ,a.action_header 
          ,a.remarks
          ,e.complexity
          ,datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp) as [man-days]

          ,CASE 
            WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
            = 0  THEN '1'
            WHEN e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
            >= 29 THEN '2'
            WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
            >= 14 THEN '3'
            WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
            >= 8 THEN '4'
            WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
            <= 7  THEN '5'

            ELSE '1'

         END AS Performance_Indicators,
         SUM(Performance_Indicators) as total



     from [s].[dbo].[tbl_de] a
        left join 
        [s].[dbo].[tbl_ce] e
        on a.reference_code = e.reference_code

         order by a.name asc
```

[image: Sample expected output]

Comment: Can you also post the error message that you are getting? I am not familiar with the brackets around the query. Is that a Microsoft SQL Server thing?

Comment: Your query does not make sense as currently written.  You have two choices, either just select only the sum of performance indicators, or add `GROUP BY` to your query and select that sum for each group.

Comment: @Huckphin I get an error Invalid column name 'Performance_Indicators'.

Comment: You can't reference an alias created in the SELECT list in other expressions in the SELECT list. Also the query doesn't make sense - you want to return every row but then a sum of that expression across rows? Which rows? Grouped by what? You could use a CTE to first expose the Performance_Indicators and *then* SUM but you need to resolve other logic issues with your query first. I suggest instead of posting your non-working query, you post table structure, sample data and desired results, then you might get a more appropriate and optimal query to get your desired results.

Comment: In addition, there is an extra coma before the first select field (a.username).

Comment: @Candy083, This result seems meaningless, is any other additional columns is there for grouping?

Answer (score 1):

Change the CASE statement to yield integers rather than strings and then use SUM(CASE...END) as Performance_Indicators.

Comment: how to change the case statement to yield integers?  do i need to use cast? or convert?

Comment: @Candy083 You change `THEN '1'` to `THEN 1`, for example. e.g. no quotes.

Comment: Yes I did that but still get the same output as Performance_indicator column , it do not get the sum

Comment: @Candy083 With what query? Not the one in the question, because that query won't compile.

Comment: I just put the sum(case...end)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT    a.username
      ,a.name
      ,a.description
      ,a.action_header 
      ,a.remarks
      ,e.complexity
      ,datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp) as [man-days]

      ,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        = 0  THEN 1
        WHEN e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 29 THEN 2
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 14 THEN 3
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 8 THEN 4
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        <= 7  THEN 5
        ELSE 1
     END) AS total
 from [s].[dbo].[tbl_de] a
    left join 
    [s].[dbo].[tbl_ce] e
    on a.reference_code = e.reference_code
GROUP BY a.username
      ,a.name
      ,a.description
      ,a.action_header 
      ,a.remarks
      ,e.complexity
      ,datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
order by a.name asc
```

Comment: I have used that query but still got the same output like 'Performance_Indicators'

Comment: @Candy083, can you give some sample data and Expected result?

Comment: @Candy083, can you give some sample data of current result?

Comment: I include the expected result above.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you should subquery on first sentence, then make main query to sum it.

Try this

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT    a.username
      ,a.name
      ,a.description
      ,a.action_header 
      ,a.remarks
      ,e.complexity
      ,datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp) as [man-days]
      ,CASE 
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        = 0  THEN 1
        WHEN e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 29 THEN 2
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 14 THEN 3
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 8 THEN 4
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        <= 7  THEN 5
        ELSE 1
     END AS PerformanceIndicator
 from [s].[dbo].[tbl_de] a
    left join 
    [s].[dbo].[tbl_ce] e
      on a.reference_code = e.reference_code
)

SELECT    a.username
      ,a.name
      ,a.description
      ,a.action_header 
      ,a.remarks
      ,e.complexity
      ,datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp) as [man-days]
      ,cte.PerformanceIndicator
      ,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        = 0  THEN 1
        WHEN e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 29 THEN 2
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 14 THEN 3
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 8 THEN 4
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        <= 7  THEN 5
        ELSE 1
     END) AS total
 from [s].[dbo].[tbl_de] a
    left join [s].[dbo].[tbl_ce] e on a.reference_code = e.reference_code
    inner join cte on cte.name = a.name and cte.description = a.description
GROUP BY a.username
      ,a.name
      ,a.description
      ,a.action_header 
      ,a.remarks
      ,e.complexity
      ,datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
      ,cte.PerformanceIndicator
order by a.name asc
```